# visual studio C# 2010 conversion issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Running to this issue. I open a project in visual studio 2010. The conversion wizard comes up, I press finish. It opens the project but fails to compile complaining about missing assembly referencs when all references are there. I suspect it is because of conversion. The .csproj file is changed from :

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build"      
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">
```

TO

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
```

So target framework has changed. How do I disable this? I am not doing anything from my side. Just opening the project and it is failing to compile. Is there some intellifence in Visual Studio 2010 to disable or NOT do this, so I can do some development and compile things. It references a ton of other projects and I don't have the option of converting them.

The project was initially developed in 2008 and I am now opening in VS 2010.

***Update***
It looks like the problem is some of the assemblies referenced from this older application have been upgraded to target framework 3.5. But this application is still targeting 2.0. So I upgraded its target framework.

Now there is another problem. Both this application and a referenced assembly have a reference to an assembly A. But application is referencing A 5.0 whereas the referenced assembly is referencing version A 6.0.  So Visual studio is complaining about that. Why do these versions have to match? Can't the application and its referenced assembly use different versions of common assembly?

The error reporting in visual studio is shady and pathetic.

Comment: What you posted is exactly the same.  The only difference is the `ToolsVersion` which does not indicate which .NET Framework your trying to target.  **What is the exact build error?**

Comment: Error 2 The type or namespace name '..' does not exist in the namespace '...' (are you missing an assembly reference?). The required references are there as dependencies and they compile fine. the project is used in prod environment and compiles on a daily basis. Something is going on with visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

No, that hasn't changed the target framework. It's changed the *tools* version. It should still be targeting the same version of the framework.

Comment: Thanks. Then what could be the issue? This conversion wizard is doing something to project and it doesn;t compile anymore.

Comment: @user236215: Well it sounds like you've now got a different problem which has very little to do with the upgrading process. I think it would be better to ask that separately.

Answer (score 0):

Any particular assembly? are the missing references from .NET fwk or your own assemblies?
I recall that you can skip the converter by incrementing the version number from 10 to 11 in the csproj file (if you come from vs2008 that is)

Comment: No all our assemblies. None of the system assemblies. those assemblies also exist as dependencies in the same solution

Comment: Hmmmm, from what vs version and fwk version are you migrating to?

Comment: I don't want to migrate anything. I just want to make some edits in my Visual Studio 2010. Keep everything else same. No meta file changes

Comment: But what were you using before?

Comment: Although I do have to add a new reference, but there is no migration involved.

Comment: You say you wanna make your edits in 2010, that means that the solution and its projects were made with a previous version of VS (thats why the wizard appears). Is it 2008 or something older?

Comment: I understand your question now. I actually don't know. Is there a way to check?

Comment: Basically everytime that conversion wizard pops up, it makes some changes that fails compilation with these missing asembly errors

Comment: Please, tell me what version of VS was being used before you wanted to use 2010, it may help us help you

Comment: I understand but I don't know. It was owned by an old team that is no longer around. I will ask around. In the meantime, is there a way to find out from project meta files?

Comment: yes, open the sln it should be the first line version 11 is vs2010

Comment: change it to 11 and reopen the solution

Comment: changed format version to 11. But I get the exact same behavior. It runs conversion wizard and doesn't compile.

Comment: Well, then check if your projects are not being migrated to 4.0. Are you on a 64 bit os?

Answer (score 0):

Update It looks like the problem is some of the assemblies referenced from this older application have been upgraded to target framework 3.5. But this application is still targeting 2.0. So I upgraded its target framework.

Now there is another problem. Both this application and a referenced assembly have a reference to an assembly A. But application is referencing A 5.0 whereas the referenced assembly is referencing version A 6.0. So Visual studio is complaining about that. Why do these versions have to match? Can't the application and its referenced assembly use different versions of common assembly?

The error reporting in visual studio is shady and pathetic.